# Bulk upload large number of files to Azure from local file system

Tags: c#, file, azure, model-view-controller, upload

What is the best way for an admin user of a website to upload 10,000+ images spread across 2,000 sub-directories?

I have a c# MVC .Net web app where 4 times a year the business need to replace 10,000+ images. They have them on a network share, there is 1 parent directory, and then around 2,000 sub-directories underneath, each housing multiple image files.

I know how to do write to BLOB storage, parallel Tasks, etc., but how can the app running on Azure navigate the client side local file storage to find all the files in the sub-directories to upload them?

Answer (score 0):

You can run AzCopy tool on the local network where the local files are, and use the `/S` flag to copy the files in a subfolder: [Upload all blobs in a folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy#upload-all-blobs-in-a-folder)

Comment: I don't think that is an option.   "After installing AzCopy on Windows using the installer, open a command window and navigate to the AzCopy installation directory on your computer - where the AzCopy.exe executable is located".   The admins who will run this can logon to the website from any machine and the app doesn't have access to install software onto client machines.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I suggest you could directly write a command-line code or exe for the client admin to upload file.

Since our web app have no permission to access client's resources.If you want your web app access the client resources, you need use special ways like Relay Hybrid Connections or VNET.

It also need the client admin to config the client machine to allow the azure web app access.

In my opinion, the most easily way you could write a exe(it will auto upload the file to azure storage using datamovement library) which will run by the scheduled job in the client-side.